# CodeMirror and jQuery .keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

It's hard to explain, but when I type in a regular textarea, I want it to update a CodeMirror textarea.  I am using jQuery's keyup();, but it isn't working, and I'm not sure why.  What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/mretchin/VH25w/14/

To test, merely type in #test1

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: [CodeMirror Manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#fromTextArea)

check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/VH25w/17/)**

1. used `setValue`, instead of referencing textarea used `codemirror` object
2. modified jquery wrapper for textarea

Hope this helps

Comment: Also fixed selector for input textarea, fixed jQuery wrapper for text area in event callback, referenced the CodeMirror object rather than the textarea that it was attached to.  That's at least 4 problems in 8 lines of code.

Comment: @OldPro Im sorry, i did not get you :|

Comment: I was pointing out that you corrected at least 4 errors in the OP's code even though you only pointed out one.

Comment: @OldPro: oh yea, i kind of assumed the rest, but thanks, will update answer